# svn: how to list last tags from svn command line?

Tags: windows, svn, tags, tortoisesvn

Whe have built a packager who diff the last due tag in svn and prepare directory folding and copy the 'diff' files in the right plave.

but we must enter on commnand line the two tag name, and so we must consult revision graph (from windows).

Is there a way to list tags from svn command line client ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work from the command line on Windows, Mac or Linux, though it requires that the current working directory is in the working copy:

```
svn ls "^/tags"
```

Answer (score 2):

With power shell:

```
$path = (([Xml] (svn log --xml $Url --verbose --username $Username --password $Password)).Log.LogEntry.Paths.Path |
? { $_.action -eq 'A' -and $_.kind -eq 'dir' -and $_.InnerText -like '*tags*'} |
Select -Property @(
    @{N='date'; E={$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.Date}},
    @{N='path'; E={$_.InnerText}} )|
Sort Date -Descending |
Select -First 1).path
```

Where $Url is the url of you tags

Comment: @realtebo: Most of that command is just invocation of `svn`. The rest is an elaborate `grep`, `cut`, `sort` and `head`. I would have written it a little differently though, I guess.